# NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined in Python

Tags: python, reduce, python-3.2

I'm using Python 3.2. Tried this:

```
xor = lambda x,y: (x+y)%2
l = reduce(xor, [1,2,3,4])
```

And got the following error:

```
l = reduce(xor, [1,2,3,4])
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

Tried printing `reduce` into interactive console - got this error:

```
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

Is `reduce` really removed in Python 3.2? If that's the case, what's the alternative?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

It was moved to [`functools`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

Comment: @julio.alegria: Because [Guido hates it](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

Comment: The article referenced in @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams makes some really good points about how most cases can be written in a more readable fashion.  For me, it's by writing `sum(item['key'] for item in list_of_dicts)`.

Comment: This should be in the core language

Comment: Yet another reason why "python" is not a stable language. First they had python2 and python3 that have intentionally incompatible `print` and now this!

Answer (score 275):

You can add

```
from functools import reduce
```

before you use the reduce.

Comment: The previous user has already answered the question and the answer is same as that of his answer

Answer (score 10):

Or if you use the six library

```
from six.moves import reduce
```

Answer (score 4):

Reduce function is not defined in the Python built-in function.
So first, you should import the reduce function

```
from functools import reduce
```

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this.

```python
# Use reduce function

from functools import reduce

def reduce_func(n1, n2):

    return n1 + n2


data_list = [2, 7, 9, 21, 33]

x = reduce(reduce_func, data_list)

print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case I believe that the following is equivalent:

```
l = sum([1,2,3,4]) % 2
```

The only problem with this is that it creates big numbers, but maybe that is better than repeated modulo operations?

Comment: Repeated modulo operations are useful when it helps to keep numbers small. Summing numbers won't create large numbers unless you sum A LOT of numbers, so in this case it wouldn't help. Especially since not doing so allows the use of the built-in sum function, which will run much faster than repeated application of a user-defined function

Answer (score 1):

you need to install and import reduce from `functools` python package