# Python - find intersection of values in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

Im writing a function to handle multiple queries in a boolean AND search.
I have a dict of docs where each query occurs= `query_dict`

I want the intersection of all values in the query_dict.values():

```
query_dict = {'foo': ['doc_one.txt', 'doc_two.txt', 'doc_three.txt'],
              'bar': ['doc_one.txt', 'doc_two.txt'],
              'foobar': ['doc_two.txt']}

intersect(query_dict)

>> doc_two.txt
```

I've been reading about intersection but I'm finding it hard to apply it to a dict.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: its not very clear what you actually are trying to do ...

Answer (score 14):

```
In [36]: query_dict = {'foo': ['doc_one.txt', 'doc_two.txt', 'doc_three.txt'],
              'bar': ['doc_one.txt', 'doc_two.txt'],
              'foobar': ['doc_two.txt']}

In [37]: reduce(set.intersection, (set(val) for val in query_dict.values()))
Out[37]: set(['doc_two.txt'])
```

In [41]: query_dict = {'foo': ['doc_one.txt', 'doc_two.txt', 'doc_three.txt'],
              'bar': ['doc_one.txt', 'doc_two.txt'],
              'foobar': ['doc_two.txt']}

`set.intersection(*(set(val) for val in query_dict.values()))` is also a valid solution, though it's a bit slower:

```
In [42]: %timeit reduce(set.intersection, (set(val) for val in query_dict.values()))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.78 us per loop

In [43]: %timeit set.intersection(*(set(val) for val in query_dict.values()))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.28 us per loop
```

Comment: Instead of `reduce`, `set.intersection(*(set(val).. etc))` should work too.

Comment: @DSM: that would work too, but mine's faster. See my updated answer

Comment: not if you compare the time it takes to type the extra characters, depending on how many times you perform the op..

Comment: `reduce` is no longer available from the standard library, use `functools.reduce` instead, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689184/nameerror-name-reduce-is-not-defined-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
first = query_dict.values()[0]
rest = query_dict.values()[1:]
print [t for t in set(first) if all(t in q for q in rest)]
```