# Installing urllib3 for a non-standard Python version

Tags: python

The server I'm coding on has a Python 2.4 binary available in `/usr/bin/` and a Python 3.0 binary available in `$HOME/bin/`. I need to install `urllib3` for use with Python 3, but `easy_install` of course uses the python available system-wide. `easy_install` installed `urllib3` just fine for Python 2.4. I tried to run it with Python 3 but it complains about missing modules:

```
$ ~/bin/python3.0 /usr/bin/easy_install --prefix=/home/web/local urllib3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

How might I work around this? Note that I did install `pip` with `easy_install` but `pip` is missing too many dependencies, so I'm stuck with `easy_install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting because `easy_install` isn't installed for Python3.

You want to first install `easy_install` for Python3 by following the instructions here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ python3.0 distribute_setup.py
```

Then you'll be able to run `~/bin/easy_install`, or `easy_install-3.0` to install `urllib3`:

```
$ easy_install-3.0 urllib3
```

Now! Note that urllib3 doesn't officially support Python 3.0… 3.2 is the first supported version, and in general Python 3.2 is the version most library authors are targeting these days, so it might be worth considering switching to 3.2 (not to mention that it's much faster, and other happy things).

Comment: The distribute_setup.py package relies on `reduce()`, however [the reduce() function has been removed from Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689184/python-name-reduce-is-not-defined).

Comment: Does it? Running with Python 3.2, distribute_setup seems to work without issue :\

Comment: Thanks. This Python 3.0 install might be botched.