# How to add items of multiple panda dataseries in a list - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a list 'final_value' which contains panda series with data below. I need to add the vales of multiple panda series into one series. 
Can anyone please help me.

Need to add values according to their index value.

I tried `final_value[i].add(final_value[i+1])` in a loop.  But did not work

Data:

```
[0      0.000000
1     14.522873
2     21.677418
3     10.791055
4      0.000000
5      7.176507
Name: (FDIUSGD Index, PX_LAST), Length: 6, dtype: float64, 
0    -16.276548
1    -16.276548
2    -15.761264
3    -16.276548
4    -16.276548
5    -17.822402
Name: (USHBMIDX Index, PX_LAST), Length: 6, dtype: float64, 
0      0.000000
1      5.972322
2     15.255200
3     -3.498313
4      2.698414
5      3.083199
Name: (USPHNSA Index, PX_LAST), Length: 6, dtype: float64,
```

Expected output:

```
0     -16.276548
1     4.218647
2     21.171354
3    -8.983806
4    -13.578134
5    -7.562696
```

Thanks!

Comment: Need to perform Row-wise addition

Comment: All series has same length. While copy paste data, i would have missed some rows.

Comment: I got the problem.I will fix it.  Ideally length of each series will be same

Comment: Using functools reduce is better than 5x faster than pd.concat and sum

Comment: Okie. Let me try. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` on `axis=1` and `sum` row-wise

```
In [597]: pd.concat(final_value, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
Out[597]:
0   -16.276548
1     4.218647
2    21.171354
3    -8.983806
4   -13.578134
5    -7.562703
dtype: float64
```

Details

```
In [598]: final_value
Out[598]:
[0     0.000000
 1    14.522873
 2    21.677418
 3    10.791055
 4     0.000000
 5     7.176500
 Name: 1, dtype: float64, 0   -16.276548
 1   -16.276548
 2   -15.761264
 3   -16.276548
 4   -16.276548
 5   -17.822402
 Name: 1, dtype: float64, 0     0.000000
 1     5.972322
 2    15.255200
 3    -3.498313
 4     2.698414
 5     3.083199
 Name: 1, dtype: float64]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
final_value = [
    pd.Series(1, range(5)),
    pd.Series(2, range(5)),
    pd.Series(3, range(5))
]
```

Just use `sum`

```
sum(final_value)

0    6
1    6
2    6
3    6
4    6
dtype: int64
```

Or you could use `np.sum`

```
pd.Series(np.sum([s.values for s in final_value], 0), final_value[0].index)

0    6
1    6
2    6
3    6
4    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Timing:  1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop  functools reduce still wins.

Comment: This wins at golf (-:  But now that you brought it up.

Comment: Hole-in-one Yes, it does.

Comment: Timing np.sum method. 10000 loops, best of 3: 164 µs per loop  crushes functools reduce.  You win!

Comment: I bow in your presence, Great Circle One.

Comment: Great... now I'm blushing

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(pd.Series.add, final_value)
```

Example:

```
print(final_values)
```

Input df:

```
[0     0.000000
1    14.522873
2    21.677418
3    10.791055
4     0.000000
5     7.176507
Name: 1, dtype: float64, 0   -16.276548
1   -16.276548
2   -15.761264
3   -16.276548
4   -16.276548
5   -17.822402
Name: 1, dtype: float64, 0     0.000000
1     5.972322
2    15.255200
3    -3.498313
4     2.698414
5     3.083199
Name: 1, dtype: float64]


from functools import reduce
reduce(pd.Series.add,final_value)
```

Output:

```
0   -16.276548
1     4.218647
2    21.171354
3    -8.983806
4   -13.578134
5    -7.562696
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

## Timings....

John's Method

```
%timeit pd.concat(final_value, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 3.06 ms per loop

functools reduce method

```
%timeit reduce(pd.Series.add, final_value)
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 551 µs per loop

Comment: @piroot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689184/nameerror-name-reduce-is-not-defined-in-python

Comment: Thanks for Ur kind help!

Comment: great solution!

Comment: @Vaishali Thank you.