# Concatenate multiple pandas series efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, series

I understand that I can use `combine_first` to merge two series:

```
series1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
series2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index=['f','g','h','i','j'])
series3 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index=['k','l','m','n','o'])

Combine1 = series1.combine_first(series2)
print(Combine1
```

Output:

```
a    1.0
b    2.0
c    3.0
d    4.0
e    5.0
f    1.0
g    2.0
h    3.0
i    4.0
j    5.0
dtype: float64
```

What if I need to merge 3 or more series?

I understand that using the following code: `print(series1 + series2 + series3)`yields:

```
a   NaN
b   NaN
c   NaN
d   NaN
e   NaN
f   NaN
...
dtype: float64
```

Can I merge multiple series efficiently without using `combine_first` multiple times?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249866/how-to-add-items-of-multiple-panda-dataseries-in-a-list-python/

Comment: ^ nope, it isn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Combine Series with Non-Overlapping Indexes

To combine series vertically, use `pd.concat`.

```
# Setup
series_list = [
    pd.Series(range(1, 6), index=list('abcde')),
    pd.Series(range(1, 6), index=list('fghij')),
    pd.Series(range(1, 6), index=list('klmno'))
]
```

```
pd.concat(series_list)

a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
f    1
g    2
h    3
i    4
j    5
k    1
l    2
m    3
n    4
o    5
dtype: int64
```

---

### Combine with Overlapping Indexes

```
series_list = [
    pd.Series(range(1, 6), index=list('abcde')),
    pd.Series(range(1, 6), index=list('abcde')),
    pd.Series(range(1, 6), index=list('kbmdf'))
]
```

If the Series have overlapping indices, you can either combine (add) the keys,

```
pd.concat(series_list, axis=1, sort=False).sum(axis=1)

a     2.0
b     6.0
c     6.0
d    12.0
e    10.0
k     1.0
m     3.0
f     5.0
dtype: float64
```

Alternatively, just drop duplicates values on the index if you want to take only the first/last value (when there are duplicates).

```
res = pd.concat(series_list, axis=0)
# keep first value
res[~res.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
# keep last value
res[~res.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Comment: concat is not that fast though for large data

Answer (score 5):

Presuming that you were using the behavior of `combine_first` to prioritize the values of the series in order as `combine_first` is meant for, you could succinctly make multiple calls to it with a lambda expression.

```
from functools import reduce
l_series = [series1, series2, series3]
reduce(lambda s1, s2: s1.combine_first(s2), l_series)
```

Of course if the indices are unique as in your current example, you can simply use `pd.concat` instead.

**Demo**

```
series1 = pd.Series(list(range(5)),index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
series2 = pd.Series(list(range(5, 10)),index=['a','g','h','i','j'])
series3 = pd.Series(list(range(10, 15)),index=['k','b','m','c','o'])

from functools import reduce
l_series = [series1, series2, series3]
print(reduce(lambda s1, s2: s1.combine_first(s2), l_series))

# a     0.0
# b     1.0
# c     2.0
# d     3.0
# e     4.0
# g     6.0
# h     7.0
# i     8.0
# j     9.0
# k    10.0
# m    12.0
# o    14.0
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: While in principle, this is the same as my answer, the touch with reduce is quite nice!

Comment: No worries my friend. You get a +1 from me.

Comment: @Mitch I guess I have a lot to learn because I dun quite understand the objective/purpose of using 'reduce' in this instance

Comment: @KaneChew We want to apply `combine_first ` first to `series1` and `series2`, and then to that result and `series3`. `reduce` with a lambda works nicely for this - first try [checking out the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with the addition example and hopefully it will make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with what @codespeed has pointed out in his answer.

I think it will depend on user needs. If series index are confirmed with no overlapping, concat will be a better option. (as original question posted, there is no index overlapping, then concat will be a better option)

If there is index overlapping, you might need to consider how to handle overlapping, which value to be overwritten. (as example provided by codespeed, if index are matching to different values, need to be careful about combine_first)

i.e. (note series3 is same as series1, series2 is same as series4)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


series1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
series2 = pd.Series([2,3,4,4,5],index=['a','b','c','i','j'])
series3 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
series4 = pd.Series([2,3,4,4,5],index=['a','b','c','i','j'])


print(series1.combine_first(series2))



a    1.0
b    2.0
c    3.0
d    4.0
e    5.0
i    4.0
j    5.0
dtype: float64



print(series4.combine_first(series3))



a    2.0
b    3.0
c    4.0
d    4.0
e    5.0
i    4.0
j    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use combine_first if you want one series's values prioritized over the other. Its usually used to fill the missing values in the first series. I am not sure whats the expected output in your example but looks like you can use concat

```
pd.concat([series1, series2, series3])
```

You get

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
f    1
g    2
h    3
i    4
j    5
k    1
l    2
m    3
n    4
o    5
```

Comment: @vaishali Could you explain/elaborate what you meant by prioritized? Thanks.

Comment: @Kane Chew, say you have two series, series1 = pd.Series([1,2,np.nan,np.nan,5],index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
series2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index=['f','g','h','i','j']), you use series1.combine_first(series2) to fill the missing values on the first with the second

Comment: @vaishali I guess you meant when both series have the same index? 'series1 = pd.Series([1,2,np.nan,np.nan,5],index=['a','b','c','d','e']) 
series2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
series3 = series1.combine_first(series2)
print(series3) ' I am surprised that the values do not add up for the same index