# how to define "@client.command"?

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically I have this code:

```py
import discord
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
TOKEN = (os.getenv("TOKEN"))
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!help'):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(
        title="Help Page", description="Under development", color=0x00ff00)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)


@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Owner")
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
    await ctx.channel.send("You cannot ban yourself")
    return
if reason == None:
    reason = "Breaking Rules"
message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
await member.send(message)
# await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is banned!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


client.run(TOKEN)
```

When I run this I get the sequent error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
NameError: name 'commands' is not defined
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689184/nameerror-name-reduce-is-not-defined-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) for commands, it states to add this to your imports:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

Comment: Now it gives me this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    @client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Comment: change ```client``` to ```bot```

Answer (score 0):

`commands` isn't defined because it isn't imported in your code put `from discord.ext import commands` at the top of your code. And, you don't need `discord.Client()` bc `commands.Bot()` is a subclass of it so please remove it for it is redundant. and finally, change `client.command` to `bot.command` to make the code work.